# Run testContainers inside kuberenetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, testcontainers, cloudbees

I have to run integration tests inside a container which is inside a kuberenetes POD.

I have the folowing jenkinsfile:

```
!groovy
pipeline {
agent {
 kubernetes {
 yaml libraryResource('podTemplates/pod.yaml')
}
}

  stages {

      stage('Checkout from VCS') {
        steps {
          checkoutScm()
        }
      }

      stage('Integration Testing') {
       steps {
         container('maven') {
          sh 'mvn test'
       }
     }
  }`

}
```

The pod.yaml Pod template has different containers , here its definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod metadata:  
labels: some-label: jenkins-build-agent-maven spec:  
containers:  
-name: maven  
 image: docker.artifactory.serv.cdc.fr/maven-ci:3.8.4-jdk-17  
 imagePullPolicy: Always  
-name: docker-daemon  
 image: docker.artifactory.serv.cdc.fr/docker:20.10.17-dind  
volumeMounts:  
-name: docker-socket  
 mountPath: /var/run
```

The problem that I have is that I want to run testContainers that require docker runtime with maven,
Maven is availible in container('maven') and docker runtime is availible in container('docker-daemon'), If I use container('maven') I get docker runtime not found error and If I use container('docker-daemon') I don't have maven to run tests.

I want to run the tests using jenkinsfile as showed above? is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: no need to use separate container for running docker
just attach `/var/run` to `maven-ci` and everything should work

Comment: I was strugling to find a solution, it is working by attaching /var/run to maven-ci, thank you @MikhailZnak

Comment: added comment like an answer for other people.
you can improve it with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to use separate container for running docker just attach /var/run to maven-ci and everything should work